# Clarifying a Textbook Question: Judson's Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a small question about the textbook we are using (which is in pdf form here:http://abstract.ups.edu/download.html). Question 23 on page 73 asks: Let a,b be elements of G. Prove that: the order of a is the same as the order of a inverse...

I am wondering if the group G is implied to be cyclic, and if this information is necessary to do the proofs.

Answer (score 1):

The order of an element $a\in G$ only depends on the powers of $a$, so it's not restrictive to consider just $\langle a\rangle$, which is cyclic. But the result is true in any group.

The proof of course depends on how the order of an element is defined, or on what it's already known. If you have proved that the order of $a$ is an integer $n>0$ such that

1. $a^n=1$
2. if $0<m<n$, then $a^m\ne 1$

then you can do it quickly.

Let $n$ be the order of $a$; then

1. $(a^{-1})^n=1$ because …
2. If $0<m<n$, then $(a^{-1})^m\ne1$ because …

and so the order of $a^{-1}$ is $n$.

If the definition of the order of $a$ is “the number of elements in $\langle a\rangle$”, then it's even easier: $\langle a\rangle=\langle a^{-1}\rangle$, because …

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not. Suppose that $|a|\neq|a^{-1}|$. Let $|a|=n$. What can you say about $(aa^{-1})^n$, using the fact that $aa^{-1}=a^{-1}a$?